# how to remove many If blocks

Tags: java, json

I have a json request which has few required fields. In my code initial check is to check for the required fields and if they are missing then throw an error with field names which are missing. What can be the best way to achieve this. Below is my code

```
Boolean isRequiredFlag = true;
    if(String.isBlank(custReq.partnerId) || String.isBlank(custReq.partnerRepName) || String.isBlank(custReq.name.first) || String.isBlank(custReq.name.last)
      || String.isBlank(custReq.address.addrLine1) || String.isBlank(custReq.address.city) || String.isBlank(custReq.address.state) || String.isBlank(custReq.address.postalCode)
      || String.isBlank(custReq.phones.phone)){
        isRequiredFlag = false;

    }
```

The above block works but it is not possible to get which field/fields are empty. One possible solution is to make many if statements but if someone can suggest a better way to do this I would highly appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to create a map of the required field names and their values, then filter the map for blank field values:

```
Map<String, String> requiredFields = new HashMap<String, String>();
requiredFields.put("partnerId", custReq.partnerId);
requiredFields.put("partnerRepName", custReq.partnerRepName);
requiredFields.put("name.first", custReq.name.first);
...
requiredFields.put("phones.phone", custReq.phones.phone);
```

To filter the map and gather the names of the fields that have empty values (in Java 8):

```
List<String> missingFieldNames =
    requiredFields.entrySet()
                  .stream()
                  .filter(entry -> StringUtils.isBlank(entry.getValue()))
                  .map(entry -> entry.getKey())
                  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Now you have the missing field names. And to set the flag:

```
Boolean isRequiredFlag = missingFieldNames.isEmpty() ? true : false;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using an iterator to loop through the properties should be a good idea:

```
Boolean isRequiredFlag = true;
JSONObject custReqObj = new JSONObject(custReq);
Iterator<?> custReqKeys = custReqObj.keys();

while(custReqKeys.hasNext()){
    String key = (String)custReqKeys.next();
    String value = custReqObj.getString(key);
    if(String.isBlank(value)) {
        isRequiredFlag = false;
    } 
}
```